# The HDMI does not provide sound

Tags: sound, 13.10, hdmi

I have A10-6800 AMD APU and the HDMI port is off the motherboard (ASRock FM2A88X-ITX+).  The system is running 13.10.

I bought a new HDMI cable and swapped them out to see if that worked.  It did not work.

The HDMI does not appear in the sound settings section, however my wireless headset/mic does show up and works perfectly when selected.

Need help.

Comment: So, does the HDMI port provide video output?

Comment: Yes.  Very good graphics.

Comment: Also, the HDMI sound is enabled in the UEFI.

Comment: hmmm... What are you connecting the HDMI to?

Comment: Toshiba 48" flat panel TV.  Don't know what type of display, not home right now.

Comment: I guess its safe to say nobody has a clue how to fix this problem.  Disappointing....

Comment: Please run `alsamixer` first and unmute your S/PDIF channels by pressing `m`-key. If this does not help, post your `aplay -l` output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my advice to you would be to try to isolate the problem and then try to find the cause.

Have you tested the sound through the HDMI cable from an device? Maybe another computer or a dvd player? Or plug the ubuntu + HDMI into something other than the target TV? Just to be sure that the cable and the TV work.

Then when you are sure the problem is in the ubuntu system, then you focus should be on  a couple possibilities in the hardware itself, the firmware, and then the configuration.

For hardware errors, Look in the log files, syslog or Xorg.0.log. After a boot of the system, any hardware problems might be evident if present.

For the firmware and configuration, look up the actual hardware you have and find out what the kernel driver is. Then google the hardware for people who have workarounds for your setup. This is a good resource: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: I got another computer, and it works fine with the TV, with two different HDMI cables.  Glad to see a response after nothing for a while.  Will try these ideas later tonight.